# Macbook - Out of HD space

Tags: mac, hard-drive, macbook

Ok, so my Macbook was getting low on space but I still had a few gigs left. I wanted to show the first episode of this anime to a friend, so I grabbed a big torrent intending to only have it download the first file. I believe my error occurred due to it attempting to allocate the full space for the torrent before I could tell it not to download all files. In any case, here's my situation now:

The df command shows 100% usage with about 900mb free. I've deleted a good 20-30 gigs of junk and this does not change. I went through Vuze and told it to delete the torrent AND all data. My drive is still full. In the Activity Monitor, under disk utilization, there are two "disks" in a drop down -- "Macintosh HD" and my user account. The results for Macintosh HD are similar to what is shown by the df command. The info for the user account shows usage of over 400gigs when my drive is only a 250.

So it seems no matter how much I delete, it stays full. Anyone got a clue what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: I presume you emptied the trash?

Comment: Can you post the output here of: "df -h", "du -sh ~/.Trash"

Comment: Possible dupe? http://superuser.com/questions/8377/somethings-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Comment: Macintosh:~ me$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   220Gi  219Gi  255Mi   100%    /
devfs          109Ki  109Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
fdesc          1.0Ki  1.0Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /home
/dev/disk1s2   465Gi  465Gi  223Mi   100%    /Users/me


Macintosh:~ me$ du -sh .Trash
0B    .Trash

Comment: /dev/disk0s2 220Gi 219Gi 255Mi 100% /
/dev/disk1s2 465Gi 465Gi 223Mi 100% /Users/me

Comment: sorry for crappy formatting there, but it actually is showing the huge usage of the user directory

Comment: It's preferable to "edit" your existing question when you have more information to add; and you can format accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go to the download directory and just double check that you have actually deleted it and if it is not there, check the recycle bin or whatever it is called on a mac. When I use Utorrent, if I tell it to delete something, it will actually move it to recycle bin and not delete it all together (has saved me a few times!)

Comment: I've been through and through my downloads directory, ensuring everything is gone. Trash is empty. Disk usage according to the command du appears accurate and is shrinking as I delete stuff. I did most of my deleting from the command line, so it didn't end up in the trash, which is definitely empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could try booting into safe mode - hold down shift when you turn the computer on. On the login box it will tell you are in safe mode, and there's no core image, so animations are all choppy.

Try the same commands here, it clears caches and various other things, so on a reboot to normal mode things might be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention in my previous posts that I have tried rebooting normally, but never into safe mode. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: after booting into safe boot, things look the same. I'll add that du -sh /Users/me shows 97gb, which is what I would expect. There is no other account using any space on the machine. I should have tons of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Us a program like [WhatSize](http://www.id-design.com/software/whatsize/) or [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) to see what's taking up your space.

Answer (score 0):

You've got directory corruption and probably massive disk fragmentation which will impact in performance and may make the mac unstable.

Boot from the system disks, run disk utility and repair the disk.  If it fails either buy [Diskwarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/Diskwarrior/index.html) (approx $100) or reinstall the OS (archive and install in Leopard or just a straight upgrade in Snowie).

Tackling the defragmentation either buy [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php) or if you have an external HD - clone the drive using [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/), write out your Macbook HD using Disk Utility and clone the drive back.

If you've already got an up to date Time Machine backup, just clean install OS and restore.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using FileVault to encrypt the contents of your home directory. That's why your home directory shows up as another volume, and also why you appear to be taking up much more space than the actual size of your hard drive. It's also probably why you can't recover free space, as FileVault only frees up space from deleted files when you restart. So restarting should recover that free space.